# Wand Python multi-size icon

Tags: python, ico, magickwand, wand

i'm trying to use [Wand](http://wand.readthedocs.org) to create a multi-size ico, but i don't find anything talking about that, only normal conversion, to ico... i've found "Sequences":

https://wand.readthedocs.org/en/latest/roadmap.html

and sequences look like what i need, but i only see samples trying to read the multiple images, but not how to create, am i missing something? or is not possible?

or is it possible to do using PIL/PILLOW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `append()` a single image to `Image.sequence` list.  For example:

```
from wand.color import Color
from wand.image import Image


with Image(width=32, height=32, background=Color('red')) as ico:
    with Image(width=16, height=16, background=Color('green')) as s16:
        ico.sequence.append(s16)
    ico.save(filename='multisized.ico')
```

Result (`multisized.ico`):

[image: multisized.ico]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with creating a multi-page PDF from multiple JPEG files. In Imagemagick i used command [`-adjoin`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#adjoin). In Wand i did the following:

```
from glob import glob
from wand.image import Image

files = glob('*.jpg')
with Image() as orig: # create empty Image object
    for f in files:
        page = Image(filename=f)
        orig.sequence.append(page)
    orig.save(filename='result.pdf')
```